# Recommend please : static site generator without ruby

Tags: html, web

I very, very like octopress (read it docs) looks awesome!

But unfortinatelly i know nothing about ruby, have no machines with installed ruby, and really confused about all this racks, gem, bundle etc.

This ruby stuff looks like hell for me.

May be exists something like octopress or anything else for generate static site.

- modern (social buttons, etc, html5)
- simple (without 100500 rubish tools)
- unix style
- comments (integration with social or popular services)

Comment: https://github.com/kriasoft/static-site-starter <-- Static Site Starter Kit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the best review so far that I've read about static sites generators. If you don't want to use Ruby, you'll have to use Python at least. Or write your blog in Markdown on Github. You won't have to install any of the Jekyll dependencies and it's easy to set-up.

Check out this article: http://mathematism.com/2010/12/22/static-site-generators/

Comment: I am loving that article :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try Nikola (http://nikola.ralsina.com.ar) it has everything you described and some other stuff as well)

- It's totally HTML5 has social buttons by default (via addthis)
- It has a bunch of dependencies but then you manage it with just one command
- Unix style cookies were not being handed out while I wrote it, but hey, I am a unix guy so it's unixy at least ;-)
- Comes with disqus support out of the box

Comment: Looks really promising

Answer (score 1):

I solve this my questions with another way.

Instead using static-site-generator, I had take my favorite mojoliciuos framework, and wget -r .

Its works pretty fine for me.